# confused with php/javascript function call

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a function to generate 13 random integers between a certain range with no duplicates.

I'm not sure on the next part is correct, but I have a button that on $_POST will send to my php script which generates *1* image from the database at a time. I need it to send the random numbers from my generate_numbers function, *all 13 of them.*, because in the end I want to display 13 different images with 1 click of the button. How do I approach this problem? Do i need a queue?

```
**Button to submit to PHP form named display.php**
<input type="submit" name"display" value=generate_numbers()>
```

---

```
  var generate_numbers = function()
     {

        var i, j;
        var array=[];
        for(i=0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*14)+16);
                for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    while(array[i]==array[j])
                    {
                        array[i]= Math.floor(Math.random()*14)+16);
                    }

                }

        return array[i]; 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page with the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var rndNums = new Array(16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28);
        var generate_numbers = function()
        {
            for(var i=0; i < 13; i++)
            {
                var idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*rndNums.length);
                var rndNum = rndNums[idx];
                rndNums[idx] = rndNums[rndNums.length - 1];
                rndNums.pop();
                document.getElementsByName("nums[]").item(i).value=rndNum;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="numberForm" action="display.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
        <input type="hidden" name="nums[]">
    </form>
    <button onclick="generate_numbers();document.getElementById('numberForm').submit()">submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And on the php side the "display.php":

```
<?php
    $nums = $_POST['nums']; // array
    foreach($nums as $key => $val)
        echo 'nums['.$key.']='.$val."<br>\n";
    // ...
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent code i'll look over it some more but for now i'm getting two errors Notice: Undefined index: nums 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a php foreach loop to loop through each of the numbers. Something like this in your PHP file:

```
$images = array();

foreach ($POST['display'] as $num) {
  $img_from_number = get_image_from_number($num);
  $images[] = $img_from_number;
}

// code to display images on page
// or for JSON return $images

function get_image_from_number($num)
  // code here
}
```

If you're doing an AJAX form, you can just loop thru the returned array to create image elements on the page.

Comment: the PHP that generates the image is dealing with binary data, can I still use this loop inside?